# return computation in a python dataframe with multiple time series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with no index of format

```
stock_id    price   timestamp
..           ..         ..
```

So that multiple times-series are encoded in a single data frame.

I would like to compute the log-return (`= log S_i+1 - log S_i`) and add that information to this dataframe.

So far, I know how to compute it for one stock

```
df.set_index(['stock_id', 'timestamp'], inplace = True)
logpctchange = df0.loc[0].logp - df0.loc[0].log1p.shift(1)
```

but how can we write back that information to the dataframe, and do that systematically for every `stock_id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `groupby().shift()` to get the shift of the data by group. Then just normal division and log:

```
df['new_col' = np.log(df.groupby('stock_id')['price'].shift()/df['price'])
```

Comment: so the key is : 1) `df.groupby('stock_id')['price'].shift()` which applies the shift to each individual series of a fixed `stock_id` and then 2) the division will be performed with alignment on the two indexes `stock_id` and `timestamp`

Comment: @nicolas in short, yes.